# google cloud dataflow sdk - dependencies issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Added the dataflow dependency to the project. The project builds , but on start up ( using jetty ) I get a runtime exception

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.auth.http.HttpTransportFactory
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
```

if i remove the dependency. The start up has not issues. 
Any idea why the dataflow dependency is causing startup error.

Comment: What else is in your pom.xml file?  There is likely a version conflict.

Comment: yeh there is a conflict
Once I added the exclusion, it works fine
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: @Aayush Verma - maybe you could answer your own question with that answer then?

Comment: Yeh, I just figured this out. I will close this by answering it.

Answer (score 2):

Added the exclusion for the conflicting dependency, and it works.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```